# Empty response from form in MVC3 using a dynamically built Dictionary to build form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to create a system for editing fields inside a pdf file using a form. After the data has been edited I want to save a version. However, the requirement is that the system shall be used with, more or less, any pdf using forms. My solution to this is that I'm using iTextSharp to read in the fields in the pdf and store it in a Dictionary inside a model. To be able to store the Dictionary inside a database(using entity framework) I then made a serializer that joins/splits the dictionary to/from a string.

Now to the problem:
My problem starts when I'm saving the form. The data is arriving in the view just fine, but coming out from the view and into the controller again, there is no data coming from the fields that were created from the dictionary.
I'm assuming the problem are coming both from using a dictionary and dynamically building the form, but I'm having difficulties seeing how I'm going to solve this.

Here is the code:

The model:

```
    public class Diplom
    {
        public string filnavn { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        private Dictionary<string, string> _fields;

        private DateTime datevalue;


        // CTOR:
        public Diplom()
        {
            _fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public DateTime BestaattTid
        {
            get
            {
                return datevalue.Date;
            }
            set
            {
                datevalue = value;
            }
        }

        // Get/set, whole dictionary.
        public Dictionary<string, string> Fields
        {
            get
            {
                return _fields;
            }
            set
            {
                _fields = value;
            }
        }
                ...
                ...
}
```

Methods in the controller:
Right now the method returned to is basically commented out, Im just using a breakpoint there to inspect the object returningmodel, which states the _field dictionary is empty.

```
   //
    // GET: /Diplom/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new ProjectContext())
        {
            var d = db.Diplomas.Find(id);
            return View(d);
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Diplom/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Diplom returningmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            //var db = new ProjectContext();
            //db.Entry(returningmodel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            //db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

and finally the View(Edit.cshtml):

```
@model txt.Models.Diplom

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Diplom</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.filnavn)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.filnavn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.filnavn)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BestaattTid)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BestaattTid)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BestaattTid)
        </div>

        <h3>Dynamic fields</h3>

        @foreach(var modelfield in Model.Fields )
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label(modelfield.Key)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor( m => modelfield.Value )
                @Html.ValidationMessage( modelfield.Value)
            </div>
        }
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default model binder is probably not able to connect the list of dynamic fields submitted in the form to the dictionary in your model. As this is a very specific requirement, i'd recommend using FormCollection instead of the model binder in your post method to get all the fields submitted from your form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection form)
{
    try
    {
        foreach(var field in form.Keys)
        {
            switch (fieldToUpper().Trim())
            {
                case "FIELDNAME":
                    // assign value to your model property
                    break;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, FormCollection did the trick :) I tried this before, but I didn't search good enough in the debugger. The values from the dynamic part of the form(the foreach loop) was found as a comma separated string called "Value"(Probably due to the property name from the Model :) ). I'll just split it and add it to the proper positions in the dictionary. Not sure how safe it is to use the keyword "Value" though, might risk later on that someone uses that Key in another field, but it will have to do for now. :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: you could address that by manually creating textboxes for each dynamic field and naming them explicitly (instead of using EditorFor, which uses the property name as the control name), for instance "dynamic-<fieldname>". You should then get a list of values with the text box names as keys in the FormCollection.